# Binary tree inorder java

Tags: java

I have implemented two functions in this code first is inserting elements in a binary tree and the other is In-order traversal .Please help how to call the In-order function ,as the function is asking for a argument of type node which is needed to be given but I am new to this to got struck what to pass in it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class BinaryTree {
    
    Node root;
    
    class Node {
        
        int data;
        Node leftChild;
        Node rightChild;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            leftChild = null;
            rightChild = null;
        }
    }
    
    public Node insert(Node current, int data) {
        if (current == null) {
            return new Node(data);
        } else if (data < current.data) {
            current.leftChild = insert(current.leftChild, data);
        } else if (data > current.data) {
            current.rightChild = insert(current.rightChild, data);
        }

        return current;
    }
    
    public void add(int data) {
        root = insert(root, data);
    }

    void inorder(Node current) {
        if (current != null) {
            inorder(current.leftChild);
            System.out.println(current.data);
            inorder(current.rightChild);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write your code here
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.add(2);
        bt.add(1);
        bt.add(3);
        bt.add(4);
        bt.add(7);
        bt.add(8);
        bt.inorder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439565/how-to-implement-a-generic-in-order-traversal-in-java-binary-tree Basically you need: `bt.inorder(bt.root);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass in the root of your binary tree, which is stored in the `root` member variable in your `BinaryTree` class.  So you want to do:

```
bt.inorder(bt.root);
```

This, with the rest of your code unchanged, gives the following result:

```
1
2
3
4
7
8
```

Since you are calling a method in the same class that has the data you need to pass to that method, you could also add a new method to your class that does the same thing without having to pass in any data.  You could either use the same name as the method you already have, or some other name.  Here's the method using the same name:

```
void inorder() {
    inorder(root);
}
```

If you add this method to your BinaryTree class, your code will work with no other changes, and will give the same result.